# How to compute the similarity between two text columns in dataframes with pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 data frames with different # of rows. Both them has a column as text. My aim to compare them and find similarities and find a ratio of similarity and add this score in final data set. Comparison is between title from df1 and headline from df2. Position of these text rows are different.

**df1**

| duration | title | publish_start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 129.33 | Smuggler's Run fr... | 2021-10-29T10:21:... |
| 49.342 | anchises. Founded... | 2021-10-29T06:00:... |
| 69.939 | by Diego Angel in... | 2021-10-29T00:33:... |
| 102.60 | Orange County sch... | 2021-10-28T10:24:... |

**df2**

| DataSource | Post Id | headline |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Linkedin | L1904055 | in English versi... |
| Linkedin | F6955268 | in other language... |
| Facebook | F1948698 | Its combined edit... |
| Twitter | T7954991 | Emma Raducanu: 10... |

Basically, I am trying to find a similarities between 2 data sets row by row (on text). Is there any way to do this?

number of final data set = number of first data set x number of second data set

Comment: what have you tried ? please avoid images. Input sample data and expected output  in plain text: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Using plaintext alone, not really. You can compute a term-frequency (TF), and inverse-document-frequency (IDF), after stemming & removing stop words and this may get you close. Discussed with an example - https://developer.hpe.com/blog/comparing-to-kill-a-mockingbird-to-its-sequel-with-apache-spark/

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is a [`Cross Join`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.crossJoin.html). This way each row in `DF1` will get joined with all rows in `DF2` after which you can apply a function to compare similatiries between them.

Comment: This will not compute `similarities score`, which is what OP is asking for